# Variables in cabal files?

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, cabal

To get a peek at the Cost Centers, I've the following stanza in my .cabal file:

```
benchmark bench
  type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:       bench
  main-is:              Main.hs
  default-language:     Haskell2010
  ghc-options:
                        -threaded
                       "-with-rtsopts=-N -p -pooutput/bench -s -hT -T -i0.1"
```

The trouble is when I tweak some library code and re-run:
`cabal run bench`, the `./output/bench.prof` and `./output/bench.hp` files are overwritten.  I'd like to keep old profiling outputs around for comparision without having to move/rename these each time I re-run the benchmark tests.

I'd hoped for some sort of variable I can use with the `-po` flag, like `-pooutput/$pkgVer` or `$datetime`, but I'm not seeing anything like that in the cabal documentation.

Is there a way of doing this directly in the cabal file, or am I going to need to add another layer, say by using a shell script to first get the date then call cabal, passing in values?
eg.

```
cabal run bench +RTS -pooutput/`date +%F_%H-%M`
```

Comment: Is that kind of thing established practice? Keeping benchmark results for comparison sure makes a lot of sense, but keeping them in timestamped directories seems a bad approach to me. What would be much more useful is a Git hook that saves the result associated to each commit, and then you can use that as the baseline for experiments and also track much better afterwards what change had what impact on performance.